# Select columns by file containing primary keys

Tags: postgresql, psql

I have a text file with primary keys. Each line contains one primary key. Now I want to select the rows based on the input file. I can not find the right option for `psql` to do this. What is the canonical way for PostgreSQL to do this job?

I know I can do

```
psql -c 'select * from table' db | grep -f primary_keys
```

But this dumps the whole database. How can I avoid it?

Answer (score 0):

This assumes you are on a shell and have the `tr` command in the `PATH`:

```
psql -c "SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id IN (`tr '\n' , <file`NULL)"
```

Every newline character is replaced with `,`, and the `NULL` in the end takes care of the final comma.